# How difficult would it be to compile QuiteRss for the RPi?

Tags: raspbian, qt

How difficult is it to compile an existing application that I know is already compiled for linux and windows? 
The application I have mind is QuiteRSS 0.13.0 RSS/Atom feed reader written on Qt/С++ www.code.google.com/p/quite-rss/ 
This I love to bits - so I want a version for Pi.
From this page www.code.google.com/p/quite-rss/wiki/Packages It appears to be available for 
Arch Linux openSUSE, 
Mandriva & Fedora 
Ubuntu 
Connection and installation: 
sudo add-apt-repository 
ppa:quiterss/quiterss 
sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get install 
quiterss

Which looks promising.
Don't mid if takes hours compiling on pi - rather avoid having to set up seperate cross compiling box.

Answer (score 1):

there are qt libraries available for raspberry pi, so basically it should be not very difficult, just download the source and `./configure && make && sudo make install` and see what happens. you might get prompted to install dev. libraries for qt, though.